# _aligned_malloc doesn't return an NULL when the size is set to 0

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following piece of code:

```
cout<<_aligned_malloc(0, 4)<<endl;
```

in Microsoft Visual Studio, Windows.

This code outputs an address of a new pointer. I am confused when referring to  [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6.aspx) , who says that:

> This function sets errno to ENOMEM if the memory allocation failed or if the requested size was greater than _HEAP_MAXREQ. For more information about errno, see errno, _doserrno, _sys_errlist, and _sys_nerr. Also, _aligned_malloc validates its parameters. If alignment is not a power of 2 or size is zero, this function invokes the invalid parameter handler, as described in Parameter Validation. If execution is allowed to continue, this function returns NULL and sets errno to EINVAL.

**When the size is zero, the function should return an null pointer rather than a not-null pointer. How to explain the behavior of the above code?**

Comment: Shouldn't this be a bug report to Microsoft, as this is their non-standard function? Note that the ordinary [std::malloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc) is **not** required to return null for a zero size allocation.

Comment: Looks like a M$ bug.

Comment: the documentation is wrong or misleading. A simple step through the short disassembly reveals that the size is never checked for 0 without the padding (alignment - 1). So the only way that size can be 0 is if padding is also 0

Comment: It looks like a bug in the docs or in the function.

Comment: @PeterT - This could also mean that the documentation is as intended but the implementation is wrong.  :-)  I can also see an easy workaround in user code involving `if (size == 0)`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's primarily off-topic; this should be a bug report on the MSDN network. We can't solve this question because StackOverflow doesn't have the authority to fix Microsoft bugs.